# Select2 подключить русский язык Bootstrap JS

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, frontend, select2

Использую select2, необходимо при неверном выборе из выпадающего списка писать сообщение на русском языке:

Вот код:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Демка выпадающего списка Select2</title>  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/i18n/ru.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/i18n/ru.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:520px;margin:0px auto;margin-top:30px;height:500px;">
  <h2>Демка выпадающего списка Select2</h2>
  <select class="myselect" style="width:500px;">
      <option>Вася</option>
      <option>Петя</option>
      <option>Федя</option>
      <option>Николай</option>
      <option>Сережа</option>
      <option>Наташа</option>
      <option>Танька</option>
      <option>Машка</option>
  </select>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
      $.fn.select2.defaults.set('language', 'de');
      $.fn.select2.defaults.set('allowClear', true);
      $.fn.select2.defaults.set('width', '100%');
      $(".myselect").select2(); 
</script>
```

Строчка `$.fn.select2.defaults.set('language', 'your-lang');` выставляет языки но не все. Немецкий, польский, английский, испанский... Русский, французский например не хочет.
Есть нюанс, что строка -   дает мне то что нужно.
Но мне кажется, что это костыль.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге победил данную проблему все-таки через проставления атрибута при инициализации контрола:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(".myselect").attr("lang", "ru").select2(); 
</script>
```

Теперь локализация на русском языке работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]